# Make a button to a link in youtube in python

Tags: python, android, ios, kivy

I'm developing an app in python using the Kivy framework, I'm a noob. I have a question related to how can i make the button that when the user tap on it, it will lead him to a youtube external video.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following:

```
from functools import partial
button_instance.bind(on_press=partial(webbrowser.open, 'https://youtube.com'))
```

Change `'https://youtube.com'` to the url of the youtube video and set `button_instance` to the button that you want the user to press.